# Find a value in a column and replace the cells values beside the located value automatically

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

Worksheet 1:

> ID Number  - First Name    - Last Name -   Age
>   00001   - Alex  - Bale  - 25
>   00002   - Kristen -    Miranda -   20

Worksheet 2: (at the beginning)

> ID Number  - First Name -  Last Name - Age
>   00001 -    Joseph   - Lee -    21
>   00002  - Gerald -  Westorm -   35

I want to find a way to do the following exercise automatically, if possible with a click of a button.
Find the ID Number of worksheet 1: 00001 in Worksheet 2 ID Number column, then replace the value first name, last name and age of worksheet 1 in worksheet 2.

Worksheet 2: (after making the changes)

> ID Number -    First Name -    Last Name - Age
>   00001  - Alex   - Bale  - 25
>   00002   - Kristen   - Miranda   - 20

The list in Worksheet 1 changes with time. The values are not fixed, that's why everytime the values in worksheet 1 are changed, I need to be able to automatically find those values in Worksheet 2 and change it there.

Please help! I have been doing this manually by using find and copy and paste, but as time passes by there are more rows to change, which takes time. Any ideas or suggestions of doing this automatically is welcome

Thanks!

Comment: (1) What are all those dashes doing in your example data?  Are they part of the name and age fields, or something else?  (2) From what you’ve presented, it sounds like you want to make Worksheet 2 be a copy of Worksheet 1 (except, unexplained, the dashes seem to be different).  If so, why not just use the sheet copy functionality?  (Why have two *separate* sheets at all?)  If that’s not what you want, please [edit] your question to explain more clearly what you do want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookup formula in worksheet 2. Assuming the data starts in row 2, with labels in row 1, ID number in column A in both sheets, put this formula into cell B2 in worksheet 2 and copy across and down:

=index('Worksheet 1'!$A:$D,match($A2,'Worksheet 1'!$A:$A,0),column())

Now you only need to make sure that column A in both worksheets contains the same ID numbers.